# 'unlock-adaccount' is not recognized in Powershell on Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell

I'm trying to use Unlock-ADAccount in a powershell script running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box. This is what I get:

```
PS C:\> unlock-adaccount
unlock-adaccount : The term 'unlock-adaccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

I did find a [SpiceWorks thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2106862-unlock-adaccount-not-recognized) that says RSAT needs to be installed, but its for Windows 10. Can I even install RSAT on Server 2012 R2, and would that fix the missing cmdlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT), which can be installed via the following PowerShell command:
`Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability -Online`.

Once this has been installed you can load the Active Directory PowerShell using the following PowerShell command: `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` or `IPMO ActiveDirectory`.

Once completed the `Unlock-ADAccount` may be used among other commands from associated RSAT modules

Answer (score 1):

I guess I was just being dumb. I looked in Server Manager and under Features -> Remote Server Administration Tools -> Role Administration Tools -> AD DS and AD LDS Tools you just click Enable Active Directory module for Windows PowerShell.